# Read a filename into a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I have a file name, i can extract it as so (using cygwin and a DOS prompt):

ls REL*.xml

which produces an output as so:

REL_LVVE_HF_NV3_VC_AGC_RX_WBE_DRC_RX_WB_VIDPP_debug.xml

How do I write a batch file to read that filename/output into a  variable?

Comment: If you're already using cygwin and like the *nix style commands better, you might consider trying PowerShell rather than batch for scripting in Windows.  It's already included with all versions of Windows since Vista.

Comment: thanks, but i have to integrate this into an existing batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from command line:

```
for  %a in ("REL*.xml") do set "fn=%~a"
```

from batch file

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\dir_with_the_file"
for  %%a in ("REL*.xml") do set "fn=%%~a"
echo %fn%
```